# Choose method at run time in Elixir (function pointer types)

Tags: elixir

I want to choose the routine of the program in run time. I couldn't find any function pointer type (or a reference to a method) in Elixir.

```
defmodule MyModule do
    def method do
        choice()
    end
end
```

I want to give a method to choose at run time. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send in a function as parameter and then call that function (with `.(`...`)`) like this:

```
iex> defmodule MyModule do
   >     def my_method(choice) do
   >         choice.("hello")
   >     end
   >  end
```

and then call it by using `&` before the module name like:

```
iex> MyModule.my_method(&String.upcase/1)
"HELLO"
```